# Bounded set has finite outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The definition of outer measure is as follows: $$m^*(E) = \inf \left\{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_k) : A \subset \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k \right\}$$

If a set is bounded then for some $p\in E$ every $e \in E$, $d(e, p) \leq M$.

In my mind I interpret this as saying that every point has a finite distance less than or equal to M.  However, I'm not sure how to translate that to the definition of outer measure.  My first idea was that the intervals $I_k$ are the lengths between a fixed $p$ and $e$.  Since they would all clearly be less than $M$, then they are all finite.  Thus the outer measure must be finite.

Comment: Do you mean $$m^*(E) = \inf\left\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_k) : A \subset \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k\right\}\;?$$

Comment: $E$ is covered by the interval $[p-M,p+M]$, so $m^*(E)\le 2M$.

Comment: Inside the braces it should be $E,$ not $A.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p\in E$ be arbitrary, $I_1=[p-M,p+M]$. Then $E\subseteq I_1$, hence $m^*(E)\le l(I_1)$.

Comment: a. Why can we say that $[p-M,p+M]$ is a cover shouldn't it be $(p-M,p+M)$? b. How can we conclude on a strict inequality $m^*(E)<\infty$?

Comment: If $(p-M,p+M)$ covers $E$ then also $[p-M,p+M]$
With the above we have: $m^*(E)\le l(I_1) = 2M < + \infty$

Answer (score 2):

If $E$ is bounded, then by definition there exists a positive finite $M$ such that $|x|\le M$ for every $x\in E.$ It follows that $E\subset [-M,M].$

The definition of $m^*(E)$ usually involves covers of $E$ by open intervals. Because of that, let's note that $E\subset (-2M,2M).$

Let's think about the definition

$$\tag 1 m^*(E) = \inf \left\{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_k) : E \subset \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k \right\}.$$

If we abuse notation a bit and assume that finite covers and sums are allowed in $(1),$ then things are easy: We just take $I_1=(-2M,2M),$ which is a cover of $E.$ We then get $m^*(E)\le 4M.$

If we insist that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_k)$ and $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k$ be actual infinite series and unions, we're still fine if we are careful to stipulate that the empty set is an open interval of length $0.$ In this case we define $I_1= (-2M,2M)$ and $I_k =\emptyset$ for $k>1.$ We then see $\{I_k\}$ is a cover of $E,$ hence

$$ m^*(E) = \le \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_k) = 4M+ 0+ 0+\cdots =4M.$$

Finally, if we are in a religious cult or an ancient Greek, we might insist each $I_k$ have positive length. In this case we can define $I_1 = (-2M,2M),$ and $I_k = (0,1/2^k), k>1.$ Then the open intervals $I_k$ cover $E.$ Thus

$$m^*(E) \le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}l(I_k) = 4M + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k} = 4M +\frac{1}{2}<\infty.$$

Comment: The families that cover $E$ are countable - including finite covers. It's not necessary to go beyond $I_1$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. The notation $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_k)$ is for an infinite sum, not a finite sum. And $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k $ is for a countably infinite union, not a finite one. These are the notations being used in the OP. We can see finite sums and unions as represented this way if we take the intervals to be the empty set after some point, and are careful to define the length of the empty set to be $0.$ Continued below ...

Comment: But I chose to assume all $I_k$ have positive length, and avoid this issue.  It just takes a few seconds extra. Something is not sitting well with the original OP nor with gbox, so I thought this might help.

Comment: @zhw. I did not undersantd why we could take a close interval as the open cover of $E$

Comment: @gbox Well you're right: A bounded closed interval is not an open interval. I expanded on my original answer.